# kafka consumer keeps looping over a bunch of messages after CommitFailedException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running a multi threaded kafka 091 consumer [New].

They way i generate a client.id is using a combination of the "hostname the consumer is running on" + "AtomicInt" + "the PID of the process".

I am running into issues when I have to stop the consumer and restart. Consumer keeps trying to process the offsets that were not consumed by the previous run(about 100 of them).  But it keeps failing with this message.

```
  2016-10-21 14:22:55,293 [pool-3-thread-6] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 2147483647 dead.
2016-10-21 14:22:55,295 [pool-3-thread-6] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator  : Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group x.cg
2016-10-21 14:22:55,296 [pool-3-thread-6] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator  : Offset commit failed.
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:552)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:493)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:665)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:644)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorKnown(AbstractCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:886)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:853)
        at com.kfc.kafka.consumer.KFCConsumer$KafkaConsumerRunner.run(KFCConsumer.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-21 14:22:55,397 [pool-3-thread-6] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator  : Attempt to join group x.cg failed due to unknown member id, resetting and retrying.
......... 
2016-10-21 14:22:58,124 [pool-3-thread-3] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator  : Attempt to heart beat failed since the group is rebalancing, try to re-join group.
```

From the kakfa log, I see a lot of rebalances happening.

```
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,196] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group x.cg generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,196] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group x.cg generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,200] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group x.cg for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,200] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group x.cg for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,952] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to restabilize group x.cg with old generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:18,952] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to restabilize group x.cg with old generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:48,233] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group x.cg generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:48,233] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group x.cg generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:48,243] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group x.cg for generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-10-21 21:28:48,243] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader for group x.cg for generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordin
```

Comment: You need to Run no of consumer thread based on partition need to per partition one thread to consume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we were having long, recurring pauses [slow network, problems with external components etc.] w.r.t the external components that our consumer was interacting with.

Solution was to split our consumer into three consumer with different consumer group and Kafka config's (heartbeatinterval.ms, session.timeout.ms, request.timeout.ms, maxPartitionFetchBytes). 
Having 3 different consumers with custom config for the above mentioned properties helped us get rid of the above problem.

The general thinking is not to have a lot of external communication within the consumer as this increases the uncertainty in Kafka consumer behavior and when you do have external communication make sure the Kafka Consumer Config's are inline with the SLA's of the external components.

Comment: i had the same problem. I solved it by creating an executor service that ran long running processes.

Comment: That's one solution i guess. 
one of our interactions was using apache http client which is a synchronous call and hangs the entire app on that call if the network is unresponsive, this is an easy fix using an asynchronous http client like Netty.
There are other solutions like writing a wrapper around kafka consumer that takes care of sending hearbeats etc to consumer coordinator, and the actual consumption itself can run on a separate thread like you did.